# Can I get all of my fireBase users ID on my swift server?

Tags: swift, web-services, firebase

I'm building a swift WEB-service, and what I'm trying to doo is simple:
I'll like a dictionary with a firebase username as a key, and the User ID associated with it as the value; something like this:

```
[user1: JqDvBnWTkKW4gGmJgHGHaxHcL6y1, user2: FSdEvsdfQsDFsfst43gDmJgHGXaxHcL4F5]
```

How can I connect firebase to my swift (and not IOS app)? How con a I get the userData? Or am I doing it the bad way?

Note that I don't know a lot about web development at all. I am maybe trying it wrong.

Comment: Firebase doesn't have usernames;  it does have uid, email and displayName properties. Which [Firebase API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides/) are you going to use?

Comment: I found out I wasn't doing it the right way, I rearranged all my system and it works perfectly without firebase. Thanks for your help!